# Submenu background color in CSS

Tags: css

I am pretty new here and tryingto learn something in CSS.
I have this question: how can I change the background color of just 1 leaf in the main menù? and, how can I avoid that these change reflects in sub-menu leaves?
In the code below I need:

1. menu-item-10838 to be background-color: #e6df00
2. menu-item-10842 + menu-item-10843 + menu-item-10844 + menu-item-10845 + menu-item-10846 + menu-item-10847 to be background-color: #d7fb00
   all the sub leave should stay deafault

```css
<li id="menu-item-10838" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10838 item-level-0 opener-page"><a href="#" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">I PRODOTTI</span></a>
<div class="sub-menu-dropdown color-scheme-dark">
<div class="container">
<ul class="sub-menu color-scheme-dark" style="display: block;">
<li id="menu-item-10842" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10842 item-level-1"><a href="#" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">I SALATI</span></a>
<ul class="sub-sub-menu color-scheme-dark" style="display: none;">
<li id="menu-item-10849" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10849 item-level-2"><a href="/categoria/aceto-balsamico-di-modena/" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">Aceto</span></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="icon-sub-menu"></span></li>
<li id="menu-item-10843" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10843 item-level-1"><a href="#" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">I DOLCI</span></a>
<ul class="sub-sub-menu color-scheme-dark" style="display: none;">
<li id="menu-item-10870" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10870 item-level-2"><a href="/categoria/pasticceria-shop-online/biscotti-artigianali/" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">Biscotteria</span></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="icon-sub-menu"></span></li>
<li id="menu-item-10844" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10844 item-level-1"><a href="#" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">DALLA TERRA</span></a>
<ul class="sub-sub-menu color-scheme-dark">
<li id="menu-item-10871" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10871 item-level-2"><a href="/categoria/frutta/" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">Frutta &amp; Verdura</span></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="icon-sub-menu"></span></li>
<li id="menu-item-10845" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10845 item-level-1"><a href="/categoria/cesti-gastronomici-on-line" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">CESTI &amp; CONFEZIONI</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10846" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10846 item-level-1"><a href="#" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">LA CANTINA</span></a>
<ul class="sub-sub-menu color-scheme-dark">
<li id="menu-item-10875" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10875 item-level-2"><a href="/categoria/vino/vino-bianco/" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">Vino Bianco</span></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="icon-sub-menu"></span></li>
<li id="menu-item-10847" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10847 item-level-1"><a href="#" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">DA BERE</span></a>
<ul class="sub-sub-menu color-scheme-dark">
<li id="menu-item-10879" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10879 item-level-2"><a href="/categoria/birra-artigianale-italiana/" class="woodmart-nav-link"><span class="nav-link-text">Birra</span></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="icon-sub-menu"></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<span class="icon-sub-menu up-icon"></span></li>
```

Thanks in advance for helping :-)

Comment: fyi: It always helps to indent the code correctly

Comment: You haven't written any CSS code for the above snippet yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `background-color` for every class that should have a specific color

```css
.menu-item {
    background-color: $default-color
}
#menu-item-10838 {
    background-color: #e6df00
}
#menu-item-10842, #menu-item-10843, ... {
    background-color: #d7fb00
}
```

Comment: thanks @Deitsch. I tried before but it happens that all the sub-leaves takes the color I set. Instead I want the sub-leaves to stay default

Comment: @AlbertoTonello format your code please, it's pain to even see your structure. Also you may only keep a representing part of it

Comment: sorry for my code... maybe it is easier if you could check yourself my site: if you can go to www.gustotosto.it , chech menù in mobile view: I followed your suggestions, you see the leaf I PRODOTTI correctly backgrounded, then the sub leaves again correct background but if you open the next level (i.e. I SALATI under I PRODOTTI) all the sub-leaves take the same background color.
Should I set a background color for every leaf till the last level?

Comment: The website works perfectly fine doesn't it? And no, you should not have to set it manually for each one.

Comment: Yes, at last I did it. As I have 2 menus, the other one got "broken" but now it is ok. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor that code and use a better indentation.

You can try to use immediate children selector

```
ul > ul {
  // This target the second level ul but not an hypothetic third level ul
  background-color: #e6df00
}
```

Or you can select via your .item-level-x class